# Gradle fails on cordova / quasar

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I am trying to run cordova app from Quasar framework. Im getting this error. Dont know why. I followed this guide:
https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/preparation

I have set environment variables to:

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT  C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME         C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
Path              C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.3\bin; %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin
```

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended
> setting) ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED) Using Android SDK:
> C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Unable to get mutable Windows environment variable map
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Gradle\gradle-4.10.3\bin\gradle.BAT -p
>   C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\QuasarProject\src-cordova\platforms\android
>   wrapper -b
>   C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\QuasarProject\src-cordova\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
>
> App • Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1  App • Updated
> Cordova config.xml
>
> App • ⚠️   FAIL  Cordova CLI has failed

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing JDK 11 instead according to cordovas webpage
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/guide/platforms/android/index.html#java-development-kit-jdk